# how to upload file to Box subfolder using Java SDK

Tags: java, sdk, box

How to upload files to my Box  Sub-Folder  using either by subfolder name or ID

Example say I have 2 subfolders(subfolder1 and subfolder2) in my Box, How to upload files to subfolder2 using java sdk.

Can we upload using any new methods.

Successful in uploading files to Box root folder using the code below

```
    BoxFolder bfolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(api);
    FileInputStream stream= null;
    filePath = "c:\\UploadFile.txt";
     stream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filePath.toString());
    bfolder.uploadFile(stream, fileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to enumerate the folders till you find subfolder1, then create a new BoxFolder from that. Something like this (edit for compile errors):

```
BoxFolder bfolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(api);
Iterator<BoxFolder.Info> it = bfolder.getChildren().iterator();
for(BoxFolder.Info i : it){
  if(i.getName().equals(subfolder1)){
    BoxFolder folder = new BoxFolder(api, i.getID());
    FileInputStream stream= null;
    filePath = "c:\\UploadFile.txt";
    stream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filePath.toString());
    folder.uploadFile(stream, fileName);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. Its Working.. :-)